# Statistics on Xcode users adoption rate per version

Tags: xcode, swift, statistics

Hope that this is the right forum to ask this question. If not please help me by redirecting to the best place to ask this.

I'm looking for usage statistics of Xcode by version.

More specifically, with which versions of Xcode are new apps, or updates, compiled with.

Googling this doesn't bring anything relevant.

This is of interest to me since I am supplying a Swift compiled framework which requires a specific Swift runtime per compilation version.

Xcode 7.3.x was updated to use Swift 2.2 compiler rather than version 2.1 used in Xcode 7.2.x.

I would like to fully migrate to 2.2 , but only when there is a high enough adoption rate of Xcode 7.3.

Comment: Consider asking this on stack overflow

Comment: So you want to be able to look in the app store on your iPhone and ask "What version of XCode and Swift was Twitter compiled on"?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if SO will keep this open, but it's not really on topic at ask different so let's move it and see...